# Cocoapods and Google Analytics transitive dependencies

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a private pod which uses Google Analytics. I include GA trough CocoaPods with `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` but it keeps on failing with the transitive dependencies error.
I know there are already *a lot* of questions regarding this subject, but none of the solutions offered worked out for me.

Looked at [Google's analytics site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift), but that didn't work out. I've seen [this closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4053) and scanned [this dicussion](https://github.com/segment-integrations/analytics-ios-integration-google-analytics/issues/3).
Briefly looked at [this small paragraph](https://segment.com/docs/integrations/google-analytics/#target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries), which also clearly passes down the transitive annoyance to GA. At the bottom of the paragraph they say:

> This eliminates the transitive dependency from the App -> Segment-GoogleAnalytics -> GA to App -> GA.

And of course, checked SO as well.

---

A little background info:

- I use Cocoapods version 1.0.0
- My podfile has `use_frameworks!` (I need that because I use Swift)
- I include the GA pod with `pod GoogleAnalytics`

  - I also tried it with `Google/Analytics` and `Google/Analytics ~> 1.3`
  - Also tried adding `pod Google` before the GA pod

and not that it matters, but:

- My Xcode version is 7.3.1

---

Some solutions say that I need a Cocoapods version after `0.36`, and that the use of `use_frameworks!` should fix it. But as far as I know, and see in the generated Pods project, the GA pod still has a static lib (`libGoogleAnalytics.a`) and no framework.
This [discussion](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=609%20) has a lot of opinions and solutions, but as I already said, none work for me. Moreover, at the bottom someone said that this is a Cocoapods issue rather then something Google should fix (something with Cocoapods not taking `use_frameworks!` into account). But I beg to differ, especially since all other pods give me a framework as they should.

I had the error before when using OpenSSL, but fixed that by adding a compiled OpenSSL framework manually to my pod.

So I'm at a loss now. As for how I can fix this...got no clue whatsoever.

---

**Edit**
For now I've sort of circumvented the problem by using Carthage with the framework generated [here](https://github.com/akashivskyy/GoogleAnalytics-Framework).